# Silverlight: How do you implement validation in custom controls?

Tags: silverlight

How do you implement validation in custom controls? I am looking to replicate the standard validation logic you would see with a TextBox data-bound to a model or view-model that exposes IDataErrorInfo or INotifyDataErrorInfo.

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? As far as I know, validation is a property of bindings, and when a binding fails the event BindingValidationError is raised. There is no difference between a standard control and a custom control.

Comment: BindingValidationError: A control author generally should neither raise nor handle this event in control design and control class implementation.

Comment: Imagine you were writing your own textbox from scratch. How would you implement things like the validation tooltip?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To implement validation you should add the "ValidationStates" group to the VisualStateManager of the control.

I will illustrate the simple custom control `TestControl` with the `TestProperty` property.

Style in the Generic.xaml, depending on the state displays the blue text or the red border with the first error message:

```
<Style TargetType="local:TestControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:TestControl">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Valid" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InvalidBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InvalidBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>    
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding TestProperty}" Foreground="Blue" />
                    <Border x:Name="InvalidBorder"  BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

There are 3 states:

- **Valid** - No validation errors.
- **InvalidFocused** - Applied when you set the focus to the control in the invalid state. Default controls display the red popup as well as the red border in this state, but in my particular example I don't display it for simplicity. Users can invoke this state by using the Tab keyboard button or by clicking a focusable inner control like TextBox.
- **InvalidUnfocused** - Applied when the control in the invalid state but isn't focused.

Here is the code of the control, it contains only one property:

```
public class TestControl : Control
{
    public TestControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TestControl);
    }

    public string TestProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TestProperty", typeof(string), typeof(TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

After that if you use the **IDataErrorInfo**, the correct xaml is:

```
<local:TestControl TestProperty="{Binding SomeModelProperty, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

For the **INotifyDataErrorInfo**, the correct xaml is even simplier:

```
<local:TestControl TestProperty="{Binding SomeModelProperty}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Would you be interested in writing a full length article on designing custom controls in Silverlight?

Comment: @Jonathan Allen What does the word 'designing' mean: implementing from scratch or decorating in Expression Blend? I can write article about custom controls in general from developer's point of view, but my designer skills leave much to be desired.

Comment: What I'm looking for is the steps needed to support all of the core functionality such as templating, validation, and data binding. There are already countless articles on making it pretty once that is done. Drop me a message and we can talk details: jonathan@infoq.com

Comment: @Jonathan Allen I've tried to write the article about creating custom controls from scratch: http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/silverlight-status-indicator-control/.

Comment: @vorrtex I just followed your example and it's great. However, I found that inside custom control - you don't need to write ANY validation-related code as long as you have ValidationStates: Valid, InvalidFocused, InvalidUnfocused. I guess those are magic keywords for visual states. No code needed! No need for attributes either. Just XAML. I guess it's inherited from somewhere up the chain of Control object

Comment: @katit Yes, validation states are built-in now. I'll fix the post.

Comment: How to use with Textbox control?

Comment: @imdadhusen Implement the INotifyDataErrorInfo or IDataErrorInfo interface in your view model. You can download the sample application from the post of my blog: http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/10/01/wpf-validation-with-idataerrorinfo/

Comment: Can you see the following link where i have mentioned my issue?    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498047/validation-fired-but-red-border-does-not-appear-with-user-control-in-silverlight        http://forums.silverlight.net/t/250280.aspx/1?Validation+fired+but+Red+Border+does+not+appear+with+User+Control+in+Silverlight+4  your help would be very appreciated