# How to force validation to show on UserControl

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation, inotifydataerrorinfo

I want stock/standard red border validation with tooltip to show around my UserControl. See code below. I have main page and UserControl.

UserControl has textbox and button. UserControls binds to Id property and displays this Id inside TextBox.

Main page has UserControl and TextBox. They bound to FirstValue and SecondValue. Both properties raise error. When I type/change something in textbox - I see border and summary. When I change text in my UserControl - I see error in summary but no border and when I click on error - it focuses button, doesn't go to TextBox. How do I fix that? I want whole UserControl to be inside red border.

MainPage XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="275" d:DesignWidth="402" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Margin="3" Text="{Binding SecondValue, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
        <my:TestUserControl Margin="3" Id="{Binding FirstValue, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
        <sdk:ValidationSummary Grid.Row="4" Name="validationSummary1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainPage CS

```
using System.Windows.Controls;


namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class MainPage : UserControl, INotifyDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;
        readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> _currentErrors;

        private string _firstValue;
        private string _secondValue;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _currentErrors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            _firstValue = "test1";
            _secondValue = "test2";
            LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
        }


        public string FirstValue
        {
            get { return _firstValue; }

            set
            {
                _firstValue = value;
                CheckIfValueIsValid("FirstValue", value);
                this.OnPropertyChanged("FirstValue");
            }
        }

        public string SecondValue
        {
            get { return _secondValue; }
            set
            {
                _secondValue = value;
                CheckIfValueIsValid("SecondValue", value);
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SecondValue");
            }
        }

        public void CheckIfValueIsValid(string propertyName, string value)
        {
            ClearErrorFromProperty(propertyName);

            AddErrorForProperty(propertyName, "Bad value");
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            {
                return (_currentErrors.Values);
            }
            MakeOrCreatePropertyErrorList(propertyName);

            return _currentErrors[propertyName];
        }

        public bool HasErrors
        {
            get
            {
                return (_currentErrors.Where(c => c.Value.Count > 0).Count() > 0);
            }
        }

        void FireErrorsChanged(string property)
        {
            if (ErrorsChanged != null)
            {
                ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }

        public void ClearErrorFromProperty(string property)
        {
            MakeOrCreatePropertyErrorList(property);

            _currentErrors[property].Clear();
            FireErrorsChanged(property);
        }

        public void AddErrorForProperty(string property, string error)
        {
            MakeOrCreatePropertyErrorList(property);
            _currentErrors[property].Add(error);
            FireErrorsChanged(property);
        }

        void MakeOrCreatePropertyErrorList(string propertyName)
        {
            if (!_currentErrors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            {
                _currentErrors[propertyName] = new List<string>();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

UserControl XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.TestUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="..." Grid.Column="1" Padding="10,0" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl CS:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Windows;

    public partial class TestUserControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public TestUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
        }


        public string Id
        {
            get { return (string)base.GetValue(IdProperty); }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(IdProperty, value);
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty IdProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Id",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(TestUserControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnIdChanged));

        private static void OnIdChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool) return;

            var lookup = d as TestUserControl;
            lookup.OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Errors checking is occured inside the object which is set to the `DataContext` property of a control. As far as I see you set `this` as the `DataContext` of the `TestUserControl` user control, but you haven't added validation to this control. Also there are many other mistakes in the code and it is possible to get rid of them if to use the MVVM pattern. Anyway I'll try to launch your code and look what I can do.

Comment: @vorrtex Example is just throw-away code - I quickly copy/pasted interface implementations just for this example so you can run it. In live project it's MVVM + PRISM

Comment: @vorrtex Also, see my reply to Ekk. Why do I need validation inside UserControl? I'm validating Id and I want UserControl to be validated as whole. So, as another example I may implement 3 textboxes as a UserControl to enter Phone number. Then, I'd like Validation to work on Whole UserControl again and display red border around all 3 boxes (one rectangle). Right now I get proper validation, I just don't get UI. Again, I'm looking at UserControl as my UI element and my main form treats it just like any other Control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your example work, you should remove all the code from the `TestUserControl.xaml.cs` file and fix bindings. Like this:

```
<Button Content="..." Grid.Column="1" Padding="10,0" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstValue, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />
```

And empty code behind:

```
public partial class TestUserControl : UserControl
{
    public TestUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Next, your another question

> display red border around all 3 boxes (one rectangle)

It can be achieved by binding to the `HasError` property. According to your code it will look so:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
   <!-- ... -->
   <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsHitTestVisible="False"
            Visibility="{Binding HasErrors, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

I've added the red `Border` element which becomes visible when the `HasError` property is set to true. But you should call the `OnPropertyChanged("HasError")` somewhere in your code.

Another way: to create a custom control instead of UserControl.
I've posted excessive description how to implement validation in custom controls as the answer to [this question about validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588126/silverlight-how-do-you-implement-validation-in-custom-controls/5628218#5628218).

I can make a more concrete answer, but you should fix the code in your post by separating view model from view, because now it is difficult to implement something based on current code.
Check my post about implementation of validation using INotifyDataErrorInfo: [WPF and Silverlight Validation](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/10/01/wpf-validation-with-idataerrorinfo/).

Or you can download my validation classes [directly](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8047386/WordPress/SilverlightValidation.zip).

After that the code will be much simplier, and I will be able to help you with more complex questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check your examples. I do think my solution is to create custom Control I just don't know how to approach this since I'm new to this and it's little over my head right now. Reason I can't remove my code behind is because I need dependency property. Take my example with phone number. I'd like to bind using "PhoneNumber" property which is 5556667777 and display those in 3 boxes. So, I have to have Dependency property and logic in code behind to process this value. In my current example I just simplify it showing Id that transfers to Text in textbox.

Comment: I will work with information you gave me and see what I can come up with. If I have more questions - I will post them here. Right now I see that my real solution is to create custom control. I'm not sure how to apprach it though. For this particular example, should I subclass TextBox or start from scratch?

Comment: I tried very first suggestion change binding and understand exactly what it does but it's not what I wanted to do, it covers TextBox only. I wasn't able to make Border work, but I get the point and it's still not what I need - since it is only border and I need this corner with Baloon popup, etc - just like regular validation

Comment: @katit I create custom controls instead of user controls only when I need either to extend existing controls or to apply different styles. In your example with phone number, actually, you can do this using a user control as well as using a custom control. If to use the UserControl approach, create a view model with 3 properties which are bound to 3 text boxes and create an invisible border with popup, the Visibility property of which is bound to the HasError property of the view model. Also it will be more flexible solution because you can validate textboxes in your view model.

Comment: @katit My answer was quite abstract and vague because you had other questions besides how to fix the code. And I'm afraid that this topic is already to large, so it would be better to open new question with exact problem.

Comment: So, can I achieve what I need with UserControl or I need Custom Control?

Comment: @katit A UserControl would be enough. But actually it depends on many factors, Anyway it will not be so difficult to change a UserControl to a custom control later if it becomes necessary.

Comment: If UserControl would be enough then my original question still unanswered. My exact question was how to validate UserControl as whole (not sub control inside) and display same validation border/tooltip

Comment: @katit The validation border can be displayed using the binding to the HasErrors property. To remove borders from inner controls, you should set the ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors to false. Maybe it still doesn't answer your question, but your original post has irrelevant code and nothing about the phone number control which you've described later. It would be better either to fix the current question or to create a new question so that I have complete and exact information about what you need.

Comment: Phone was just to explain what kind of effect I'm trying to achieve. Simple border is not what I needed. I was looking for "stock" validation effect with toottip, I thought it is something that built-in into framework but after looking into TextBox's template - I can tell it has to be programmed manually. I'm just not sure how to post question like this on StackOverflow. Code sample get's real big when I get realistic scenario

Comment: @katit Leave only two files of the single self-sufficient control (because 4 files are too difficult to work) and add the following information: where and how often are you going to use the control, what should be exactly displayed in the validation summary, what are the outer dependencies of the control (a model object, a web service etc). Try to use more realistic scenario but simlify all the code and leave only what is relevant to the question

Comment: @katit Suddenly I've seen the warning "Please avoid extended discussions in comments.". Ok, just fix the question, I'll edit the answer and this issue will be finished.

Comment: I'm working on custom Control now. So, I will just post different question when I get in a trouble. Thanks a lot for so much help. I can release bounty after 2 days

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**to**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

Comment: It won't work because I do not implement INOtifyDataError inside UserControl and it's not what I want, I don't want TextBox to be validated, I need whole UserControl to be validated